# ASP.NET MVC Editor Template; Pass parameter to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my editor template in my ASP.NET MVC project:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
        .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty))
        .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("GetTypeDataforRow","MyController"))
%>
```

I am using the GetTypeDataforRow method in my controller to retrieve the data for my combo box.  Is there a way to pass a parameter into the GetTypeDataforRow method?  If so what is the syntax for this?  My drop down will display different data depending upon the parameter passed into this method.

Thanks ahead of time for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some info on this topic [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-data-binding-client-side-binding.html). Seems that the official documentation doesn't have a DropDownList branch, but ComboBox will do the stuff. It says that to pass parameters to the controller using ajax binding you should do something like this:

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
     //Ajax binding
     .Ajax()
          //The action method which will return JSON and its arguments
          .Select("_AjaxBinding", "Home", new {id = (string)ViewData["id"]})
)
```

There is one moment: you can't get the value of your combo-box using this approach because ViewData is a server side container. Instead you'll have to use JavaScript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onComboBoxDataBinding(e) {
    e.data = $.extend({}, e.data, { customParam: "customValue"});
}

</script>
```

Hope this helps you anyway.